# Why is sound gradual typing slow?

Tags: typing, static-typing, dynamic-typing, gradual-typing

There are a whole bunch of articles making the claim that gradual typing is inherently slow. The most shocking claim comes from [Takikawa et al (2016)](http://www.ccis.northeastern.edu/home/types/publications/gradual-dead/pre-treatment.pdf) who report a **100-fold** slowdown on gradually typed programs.

I simply don't believe it and want to know exactly *where* the slowdown comes from. I can believe that Typed Racket's implementation of gradual typing is slow, but not that gradual typing would be that slow in general.

Take for example this gradually typed Python program:

```
x = some_fun()
y: int = x
```

It is unsound because `x` can be of another type than int. However, if a smart compiler inserts the equivalent of an assert

```
x = some_fun()
assert type(x) == int
y: int = x
```

then the type checking becomes sound. Clearly, even if you insert hundreds of asserts everywhere in a program, a 100-fold slowdown is not realistic. What am I missing here?

Comment: What if it's an ADT like a list of int? Wouldn't you have to iterate over the whole collection at every boundary?